# Spark Cannot Connect to HBaseClusterSingleton

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase

I start an Hbase cluster for my test class. I use that helper class:

[HBaseClusterSingleton.java](https://github.com/apache/gora/blob/master/gora-hbase/src/test/java/org/apache/gora/hbase/util/HBaseClusterSingleton.java)

and use it as like that:

```
private static final HBaseClusterSingleton cluster = HBaseClusterSingleton.build(1);
```

I retrieve configuration object as follows:

```
cluster.getConf()
```

and I use it at Spark as follows:

```
sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, MyInputFormat.class, clazzK,
    clazzV);
```

When I run my test there is no need to startup an Hbase cluster because Spark will connect to my dummy cluster. However when I run my test method it throws an error:

> 2015-08-26 01:19:59,558 INFO  [Executor task launch
>   worker-0-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn
>   (ClientCnxn.java:logStartConnect(966)) - Opening socket connection to
>   server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate
>   using SASL (unknown error)
>
> 2015-08-26 01:19:59,559 WARN  [Executor
>   task launch worker-0-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn
>   (ClientCnxn.java:run(1089)) - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected
>   error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
>   **java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused**     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
>     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
>     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)

Hbase tests, which do not run on Spark, works well. When I check the logs I see that cluster and Spark is started up correctly:

> 2015-08-26 01:35:21,791 INFO  [main] hdfs.MiniDFSCluster
>   (MiniDFSCluster.java:waitActive(2055)) - Cluster is active
>
> 2015-08-26 01:35:40,334 INFO  [main] util.Utils
>   (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Successfully started service
>   'sparkDriver' on port 56941.

I realized that when I start up an hbase from command line my test method for Spark connects to it!

So, does it means that it doesn't care about the conf I passed to it? Any ideas about how to solve it?